# Nature of Integrity in Buddhism

Tags: right-intention, truth

Following an [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35330/7302) I received previously, I wonder a question I deem somewhat important:

**If a person preaches ideas or advice related to the dharma, but fails to live by those values, is this person lying?** If not, is there still a consequence in terms of the person's mind, perhaps integrity?

Comment: It's not very conductive for one self and others, but higher as the person who neither praises nor does himself under the four. No need to state that acting unvirtuose is unskillful. So the 2. lowest person.

Answer (score 3):

This is not lying unless you pretend or say you follow the advice.

Dhamma practice is a gradual exercise hence one does not become perfect at once but it is a matter of putting int the effort to increase one's perfection:

- cultivate what is wholesome which one does not already do
- increase what is wholesome which one already does
- abandone what is unwholesome which one already does
- prevent the arsing of what is unwholesome which one does not already do

Answer (score 2):

There is a Sutta to say that there are four types of persons.

- A person who helps themselves but no help to others.
- A person who does not help themselves but help others
- A person who neither helps themselves no others.
- A person who help themselves and help others

Answer (score 1):

Canonically (perhaps according to the vinaya) I think that the definition of "lying" includes "intent to deceive".

Comparing how you live to an ideal might be self-view or conceit see e.g. [How are 'conceit' and 'identity-view' not the same?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9415/254)

Note that comparison (conceit) can be beneficial in some circumstance, if you use it as guidance for betterment (see e.g. the Bhikkhuni sutta, or the advice to the young Rahula)